# Making a page scroll to a specific height after a certain amount of time, after checking scroll position is at top

Tags: javascript, scroll

Title basically says it all, I want to make a page scroll to a specific height after a certain amount of time, after checking scroll position is at top.

This is what I have so far, but i only seems to load the second function once?

```
<script>
window.onload = setTimeout("pageHeightTest();",2000);

function pageHeightTest() {
    var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
    if (top < 50){
        pageScroll();
    }
}

var scrollAmount = 0;
var h = window.innerHeight;

function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,7);
    scrollAmount += 7;
    timer += 1;
    if(scrollAmount < h) {
            scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',0.1);
    }   
}
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?
Cheeeers

Comment: window.onload = setTimeout("pageHeightTest();",2000); means window.onload = the return value of function settimeout, which is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you ever check console for js errors? `timer is not defined`

Add `var timer = 0;`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zVtKs/)

```js
window.onload = setTimeout("pageHeightTest();",2000);

function pageHeightTest() {
    var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
    if (top < 50){
        pageScroll();
    }
}

var scrollAmount = 0;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var timer = 0;

function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,7);
    scrollAmount += 7;
    timer += 1;
    if(scrollAmount < h) {
            scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',0.1);
    }   
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lacinia elit blandit sapien iaculis, et pharetra leo dignissim. Proin dignissim pretium sapien, in vulputate tortor. Sed id sodales purus, ut auctor nisi. Morbi a odio tellus. Aliquam sollicitudin leo neque, ac ultricies arcu dignissim vel. Aliquam tempor ligula porttitor, cursus massa non, posuere dui. Etiam faucibus dictum pharetra.

Proin ac magna adipiscing, iaculis ante vitae, vehicula mauris. Nunc eleifend, sapien id blandit gravida, lorem quam convallis mauris, at pellentesque metus purus eu justo. Mauris commodo lorem enim, vel semper justo volutpat vitae. Nam vel diam non justo vulputate ullamcorper nec vel turpis. Proin faucibus dolor a ipsum viverra imperdiet. Sed ultricies vehicula mi a tempus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed mi ut ligula gravida semper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

Morbi rutrum tortor eget metus ultricies tempus. Maecenas augue urna, auctor commodo egestas at, porta pretium tortor. Fusce nec eros mauris. Cras purus tortor, rutrum at tellus imperdiet, accumsan aliquam felis. Quisque facilisis tortor at orci accumsan vestibulum ut ut elit. Sed dapibus egestas metus ut facilisis. Maecenas et mauris eleifend, accumsan nisl et, scelerisque ipsum. Ut at luctus purus. Mauris id lacus porta, feugiat ipsum id, tincidunt sem. Suspendisse ornare venenatis ipsum, id elementum lectus consequat accumsan. Quisque quis eleifend justo. Aliquam erat volutpat.

Ut quis lorem vestibulum, scelerisque arcu in, aliquet tellus. Morbi tincidunt consectetur tristique. Curabitur adipiscing, nisl in tincidunt pellentesque, eros odio gravida erat, quis porta nunc massa et tellus. Proin posuere sollicitudin eros, in sodales mi convallis at. Nulla porttitor urna ut bibendum egestas. Maecenas interdum convallis lectus, vitae scelerisque augue eleifend in. Nulla quis dapibus erat, in tempor nibh. Nunc aliquet in velit sit amet vehicula. Aenean tincidunt leo ac odio fermentum sollicitudin. Cras felis turpis, consectetur vel orci eu, commodo volutpat sem. Donec eget viverra leo.

Fusce ac varius nibh, nec bibendum erat. In quam massa, aliquet vitae sollicitudin sit amet, pellentesque nec turpis. Suspendisse dapibus, metus ut blandit placerat, lectus risus vestibulum urna, eget consequat nunc nisi faucibus leo. Fusce vel vestibulum justo. Mauris et pulvinar diam, eget condimentum erat. Vivamus malesuada vehicula justo in mattis. Cras at condimentum tellus, sit amet viverra tortor. Maecenas convallis orci diam, et posuere eros semper in.
```